# Python not recognizing variable as list

Tags: python, list, types

My function receives a LIST but I am getting

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()

```
def sum_list(lista):
    last = len(lista)
    for i in range(last):
        return lista[i] + sum_list(lista[i+1])

lista = [1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 0]
sum_list(lista)
```

Comment: `lista[i+1]` is *not* a list, so why do you pass it to `sum_list`?

Answer (score 1):

lista[i+1] is an int and you pass that to your function :) hence the error

Edit: also there is a python built-in sum (if you just need the sum of a list)

```
my_list = [42, 0, 41, 74]
list_sum = sum(my_list)
```

Comment: Thank you. I know there is a built in but this is a mandatory exercise for a course. I have to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

`lista[i+1]` is not a list
You might need: `lista[i+1:]`

Comment: Thank you. Silly silly mistake.

Answer (score 1):

- You didn't call the function with the list in line 4
- You need to give a return 0 finally else it will throw an error int + None not supported

The Corrected Code:

```
def sum_list(lista):
    last = len(lista)
    for i in range(last):
        return lista[i] + sum_list(lista[i+1:])
    return 0

lista = [1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 0]
sum_list(lista)
```

Another easy to understand version:

```
def sum_list(lista):
    sum = 0
    for i in lista:
        sum += i
    return sum

lista = [1, 5, 3, 4, 2, 0]
sum_list(lista)
```